# Point subdomain to another web hosting

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain

I bought a domain from GoDaddy. Let's call this domain `abc.com`.

I've a hosting account at web hosting A with `abc.com` as my primary domain.

I created a sub-domain `pic.abc.com` and I wish it to be pointed to my *new* hosting account.

This web hosting B also uses `abc.com` as the primary domain.

The main purpose of doing this is because I only want to use web hosting B to host my `pic.abc.com` contents. That's all. Other content from `*.abc.com` and `abc.com` will be remain at web hosting A.

How to do this?

Additional notes...

1. I tried to add `pic.abc.com` as an add-on domain to my web hosting B account. Unfortunately, I couldn't do that.
2. I also tried to use URL forwarding method using DNS management service like DNS Social. It doesn't work.
3. I'm using WordPress on the `pic.abc.com` site. Both web hosting A and B running cPanel - Apache servers (shared hosting).

Comment: Are you on a shared server?

Comment: @w3d yes. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure... but if you are on a shared server then simply setting up `A` records (or `CNAME` records for that matter) won't work by itself. There needs to be something setup (ie. the subdomain) at Host B, but the main domain (abc.com) points to another server. I'm thinking that maybe Host B should be set up initially to use `pic.abc.com` and not simply `abc.com`, since that already points elsewhere. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the DNS manager in godaddy, edit the zone for abc.com, and create an "A" record that points pic.abc.com to the IP address of the new host. You might have to use a CNAME record instead of an A record, but the process is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to point your subdomain pic.abc.com to hosting B IP address. Please just login to your CP--> DNS setting--> find the A record and change it.